# Bootstrap datepicker date alignment changes when screen size is reduced

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I have used bootstrap datepicker . Everytime I reduce the screen size the datepicker changes the alignment of the dates like below.

[image]

```
  <div class='input-group date' id='fromDate'>
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FromDate, new { @class = "form-control", name = "startDate", id = "startDate", @readonly = "true" })
   <span class="input-group-addon">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
   </span>
 </div>
```

And on document onload the below code.

```
$('#fromDate')
  .datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    autoclose: true,
    orientation: 'bottom'
  })
```

I have tried giving height and width, but nothing worked.

Comment: You are not using bootstrap datepicker, instead you are using jquery datepicker, please check all your scripts and styles or follow this link https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have this *ViewPort* meta in your _Layout.cshtml file. And your Jquery ID should be startDate not fromDate according to your text field.

```
$('#startDate')
        .datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            autoclose: true,
            orientation: 'bottom'
        })
```

Hope this will fix it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, but I have used viewport meta and 'fromDate' is the id of the <div> above the textbox. Setting datepicker to the textbox too has the same issue.